# Short Story / Full story Button inside a Case Study. Why is it a bad idea?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, buttons, user-expectation, portfolio

-- BACKGROUND --

Hey I'm working on my portfolio (UX/UI) website now. The main audience will be smaller companies who don't know much about UX and case studies. But I am also looking for work and hopefully many recruiters will look into my portfolio too.

On one hand I want to present very detailed research, conclusions, re-do after testing, etc. But this might be wasting time for many readers, who don't care about it and just want to quickly look into effects.

-- THE QUESTION --

So I thought about this button option inside case study. You open a project and you have an option depending how many details you want to learn about it. If you wouldn't choose anything there is short version loaded already.

**What are the downsides of this idea? Why I should not do it?**
As far as I know it might unnecessary complicate stuff and people who don't care just scroll through the long case study anyways.

What do you think of it?
This is a quick wireframe to show the idea:

[image: A quick wireframe to show the buttons]

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a great idea considering how you intend to target 2 different key audiences.

My 2 cents would be to show that the "Short summary" is the one active by default and should perhaps be placed on the left. Also you could consider adding "view full case study" at the bottom of each short summary so viewers do not have to find it difficult to switch to full case studies on projects they find really interesting.

Comment: That's awesome suggestions that improve it a lot! Thank you Oluwatobi